# RestTemplate Bean gives OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory does not support request body buffering in spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am creating this bean:

```
@Bean("MyRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate myRestTemplate(final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.setBufferRequestBody(false).build();
}
```

And i am getting the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'KSHSignRestTemplate' defined in bla.bla.bla.MyProperties: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'myRestTemplate' threw exception with message: OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory does not support request body buffering
```

This is happening since I migrated spring boot from spring 2.x to 3.1.2. I have done hours of research but I could not find any documentation around this issue.

I slightly changed the name of the methods and classes so it's more suitable for the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but removing .setBufferRequestBody(false) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`setBufferRequestBody(boolean bufferRequestBody)` is deprecated in Spring 3. Requests are never buffered in restTemplate, as if this property is false. See [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html#setBufferRequestBody(boolean)).